# DNS Errors after sudo apt update

Tags: networking, dns

today I used sudo apt update command and I started to get dns errors. Website takes forever to load, connecting to archive ubuntu takes a lot of time. This issue is really annoying because I often get dps probe finished. Since I couldn't fix the problem, I reinstalled ubuntu but I still have this bug. My other laptop with ubuntu doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Do you experience this issue on a live version of Ubuntu on the same laptop (i.e. boot from a thumb drive)?

Comment: Yes @n3xtd00rpanda

Comment: Have you tried changing the DNS server? Otherwise it sounds like it could be something with the graphics card. Do other distros, e.g. PopOS or Linux Mint encounter the same issue? I mention those two as they're about as user friendly as Ubuntu & both use the apt package manager.

Comment: @nx3xtd00rpanda I tried to change dns server to 1,1,1,1 or 8.8.8.8 and no I don't use other distros so I don't know if this issue occurs in other distros.

Comment: ah ha I am having the same problem after updating. Atm I am using Windows for working.